Custom archive template of categories from a custom post type issue
I need to create a page template that shows the categories of some customs posts (events)
I want to make a page template that shows the categories of some customs posts (events), which I have created with the plugin "Event Manager and Tickets Selling Plugin for WooCommerce - WpEvently - WordPress Plugin"
I am attaching the code I made for the template:
<div class="mep-events-wrapper">
    <div class=''>
        <h1>Cursos</h1>
        <div class='mage_grid_box'>
            <?php
            $wcatTerms = get_terms('mep_cat', array('hide_empty' => true, 'number' => 'all', 'order' =>'asc', 'parent' =>0, 'upcoming'));
            foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) :
                ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $wcatTerm->name; echo $status->$params['status']; ?>">
                    <div class="thumbnail-image-category">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy );?> ">
                            <?php /* The image */ ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>">
                        <?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'mep_events',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'cursos',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $wcatTerm->slug,
                        )
                    ),
                    'posts_per_page' => 1
                );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                $imgurl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' );
                $title=get_the_title($post->ID);
                ?>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endforeach;  ?>
        </div>

But I can't get the thumbnail images for each category to show.
I would also like, if possible, to be able to detect if the categories contain events without available places, so that the category is not displayed.
In short, it would achieve something similar to a WooCommerce page, where the categories are displayed, only if there are products in stock.

The rule here is one question at the time. Note that in your current provided code there are a lot of mistakes: $status is not defined and there is a mistake with $params in $status->$params['status']; which will throw an error. Also, $post in get_the_title($post->ID); is not defined and should be replaced simply with get_the_title();. Try first to debug your existing code by enabling WP_DEBUG.

thanks,
I'm very bad with php code... my job is more design, sorry.
I have already fixed what you mentioned and I would say that it does not give errors. I removed the status and replaced with get_the_title(); as you indicate.
but I continue with the desire to get the thumbnail images for each category and detect if the categories contain events without available places...

You can find an example in woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail() function code on how to get the image from a WP_Term object.
